# Button is not clicked unless I click on it twice in Firefox, using selenium webdriver and C#

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver

I have a button in a web application which I want to click. I am using Selenium WebDriver, C# and Firefox version 47.0.1.

I tried using explicit wait and also tried using Actions class. But nothing works.

It only works for firefox when I add the below code (click twice)
_NextButton.Click();
_NextButton.Click();

However, it works fine in Chrome browser with : _NextButton.Click();
and fails in chrome for the code used for executing on Firefox.

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: If it is not a public web page, I think it is impossible for us to reproduce. You should at least share part of the page code and your test code with explicit waits.

Comment: Have you tried to click using an Action?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes their is some problems with IE11 and chrome in selenium is not able to work as expected. so I use double click instead of click in certain scenarios.

Actions action = new Actions(driver); action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By...path..."))).doubleClick().perform();

Comment: DoubleClick with action class did not work for me.  The below code worked instead.

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
action.ClickAndHold(_NextButton).Release().Click().Perform();